# How to block all vendor-app notification and bottom-right corner pop-ups of Windows (11) Desktop?

Tags: windows, windows-10, notifications, notification-area

They are very distractive. I want to totally silence apps running in the tray or background and prevent from from creating any windows or pop-ups unless I explicitly open the app.

In short, when I am focusing on one software, I don't want any other software to change any pixel of my screen.

For example, if someone call you via Skype, the Skype will give a pop-up window to notify you. You can only turn off the pop-up window through the Skype app. For some other app such option does not exist. I am looking for a windows setting or a third-party solution that block all pop-ups and notifications.

I've tried almost **all** the popular methods of disabling all notifications and set-up quite hours (for example, see below):

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-notification-settings-in-windows-8942c744-6198-fe56-4639-34320cf9444e

[image]
[image]

They are not effective: windows system stops to give notifications, but other apps, such as QQ, Wechat, and occasionally Skype, persist to give notifications.

Any solution or software suggestion will be good!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(A)** Settings method that catches many notifications.

Start, Settings, System, Notifications and scroll down the right side.  You can disable or re-enable any notification you wish.

[image: Notification Settings]

**(B)** A very simple way to control these in real time (and without spending a lot of time) is to right click on the app notification and select "no notifications from this app"

I have a new Windows 11 laptop and it has taken 3 or 4 days of trivial effort, 2 or 3 times a day to reduce the onslaught.

This also allows me to control what I wish to see and not see. It also helps a lot as I install new software and new notifications come up.

I use both methods effectively.

Here is a screen shot of method B (not always easy to capture!).  When the notification comes up, right click and follow the screen shot.   I chose Auto Play because I would never disable this one.

[image: Right click on Notification]

**Note:** There is no single Windows setting that turns off all Vendor App notifications. Vendors can do as they wish here.

Comment: Hi John, the Method A is exactly what I shown in my screenshot: not working for some apps. Could you please upload a screenshot for the Method B?

Comment: How can I block all vendor app notification/distraction?

Comment: You cannot possibly do that - Not possible. Vendors write their own software and Microsoft cannot tell them they cannot notify users. There would likely be a court case if they tried,

Comment: I added a screen shot for Method B as you have requested. It is nice and simple, works well and has eliminated about 90% of notifications.  I do want and use some notifications and the way I manage them is very individual and takes very little time. My screenshot for (A) provided a little more detail than the one in your question.

Comment: Hi John. Thanks for the photo. I think that only works for notification in the windows-notification tray. It does not work for notifications independently showing up as new windows or bottom-right pop-ups.

Comment: There may be some idiosyncrasies but if I manage to catch the notification,  I can turn it off.

Comment: Hi John, for example, if someone call you via Skype, the Skype will give a pop-up window to notify you. You can only turn off the pop-up window through the Skype app. I am looking for a windows setting or a third-party solution that block all pop-ups.

Comment: I have not seen such a thing. That is a function of Skype itself.  As I mentioned before, there is to big notification turn off switch . That is treading on other software vendor's turf.

Comment: Of course as an user I want to tread on software vendor's turf. Don't you want to have full control over every part of your device?

Comment: Don't you want to have full control over every part of your device?  ...........   No real need. Most notifications are ON or OFF and I have turned OFF what I want. Skype only has notifications when using it. If I am not using it, then it is not running.  So over 90% of normal notifications are easily controlled.

Comment: Make sense. Just the 10% of notification really annoyed me.

Comment: What notifications do you have that you cannot turn OFF?

Comment: I installed a new version of Glary, got a Windows Notification of an update, turned that OFF (my point earlier about real time Notifications), went o Glary and dealt with the update. So no more Windows Notifications from Glary.

Comment: Hi John. I have quite a lot notification to turn off so I am asking for a one-shot solution. Thanks again for your help John

Comment: I have not seen a notification turn off app to this point. I really do not think there is one.